# Calling class method within rake task, nothing happening

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks, rake

So I have a class method which works great for my ApplicationMailer. It finds orders that are not fulfilled, converts them to CSV, attaches them in an email, and emails them to a predefined email address.

This is working fantastically.

However, when I call this method in a rake task, it does absolutely nothing. This is the first rake task I have written and am trying to use it with heroku scheduler to send out orders to be fulfilled every night.

the code for my rake task is below:

```
desc "send daily orders to shipping"
task :send_orders_to_shipping => :environment do
    ApplicationMailer.email_days_orders
end
```

This rake task shows up in rake -vT as rake send_orders_to_shipping but when I call "bundle exec rake send_orders_to_shipping", the command line seems to pause for 5-10 seconds, like its doing something, but no error is passed back or anything and nothing happens. No orders are marked as fulfilled in the database as they are when I simply run the class method from the command line and no emails are sent.

Any help is appreciated, I am new to rake and am wondering if I have missed something in my reading?

I was instructed to put the :environment block by herokus documentation for using the scheduler addon. Could this be messing things up?

edit: here is the code for ApplicationMailer.email_days_order which works from the command line.

```
def email_days_orders
    ordlength = Order.where(fulfilled: false).length
    indordlength = Individualorder.where(fulfilled: false).length

    if ordlength > 0
      attachments["school_orders_#{Date.today}.csv"] = Order.todays_orders_to_csv
    end

    if indordlength > 0
      attachments["individual_orders_#{Date.today}.csv"] = 
      Individualorder.todays_indorders_to_csv
    end

    if ordlength > 0 || indordlength > 0
      mail(to: [ENV['SHIPPING_EMAIL_1'], ENV['SHIPPING_EMAIL_2'], 
      ENV['SHIPPING_EMAIL_3']] ).deliver
    end

end
```

Comment: You're forgetting to actually send the email. `ApplicationMailer.email_days_orders.deliver_later` (or `.deliver_now`)

Comment: I call .deliver within email_days_orders method.

Comment: Also, none of the code within email_days_orders is executed, not just the email delivery part.

Comment: Interesting. I'd guess the rake task simply fails to boot, but it should print an error somewhere in this case...

Comment: Is ENV set up correctly?

Comment: You mean my environemental variables? ENV['SHIPPING_EMAIL_1'] etc. ? Yeah all my ENVs are working fine. Also, I put a bunch of "puts" statements throughout my methods called by the rake task and none of these print to the console when I try to run the rake task. Just like nothings happening.

Comment: So apparently I do need to call .deliver_now even though .deliver is being called within the mail method. It seems that the ApplicationMailer.email_days_orders does not get executed at all if deliver_now is not added to the end. Which is so strange as simply calling the method without .deliver_now works well from the command line. If you add this as an answer I will give it a check mark. Thanks for suggesting this! I would have never tried it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to actually send the email. Try `ApplicationMailer.email_days_orders.deliver_later` (or `.deliver_now`)